# CSS Columns - force break if element is at bottom of column

Tags: css

I've got the following code where {activity_type_copy} is a cms custom field which the client inputs paragraphs and h3 tags

```
<article class="copy-container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 columns-3">
        {activity_type_copy}
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-12columns-3 -->
</article><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
```

the columns-3 class has column-count:3 set and this is working great. However at some screen sizes the h3 tags are at the bottom of the column which I'd like to avoid. See the screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

Is there a way to force h3 tags to move to the next column if they are the last element in a column?

Comment: not with css as far as i know

Comment: look at CSS properties `widows` and `orphans` they determine how many lines from the beginning and ending of the paragraph are supposed to be after or before the break.

Answer (score 2):

According to [CSS Fragmentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#break-between), you can prevent column breaks just after an element with

```css
break-after: avoid-column;
```

You can also prevent all kinds of breaks with

```css
break-after: avoid;
```

For better compatibility, use [old aliases](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#page-break-properties)

```css
page-break-after: avoid;
```

This might not work on all browsers.

Comment: That works in IE Edge but not Chrome. Will see if there is a webkit prefix that will work.